# AngularJS webapp breaks on Chrome 70 only

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, google-chrome

I have an AngularJS webapp with typescript, bootstrap and some more technologies that doesn't work on Chrome 70.
FireFox, Safari and even IE works and also Chrome 69 but Chrome 70 is failing.
As far as I can tell there's nothing in the Chrome 70 change log that should effect anything in my webapp so I have no idea what can cause this.
Your help is much appreciated.

Edit: 
It seems that a post request to the server is related to this.

Comment: what are the errors that u see in the console?

Comment: My app goes into some sort of loop and tries to re-load the controller over and over again. There's no specific error that indicates that something is broken.

Comment: No console errors at all?

Comment: Nothing related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it turns out that Chrome 70 also has changes in the V8 engine and one of them changed the .sort function to make it stable.
The bad coder who wrote this app was relaying on a very bad sort function and after fixing the function everything works.

More on the .sort function changes:
https://twitter.com/mathias/status/1036626116654637057?lang=en